# How to Fix Type 'Emits' has no call signatures, in vue 3 using script setup and typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have below code which is working fine but I'm getting below warnings in IDE :

`TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type 'Emits' has no call signatures`

Here's the code :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
export interface Props {
    currentStep: number;
    canLocal: boolean;
}

export interface Emits {
    canLocal: boolean;
}

const emit = defineEmits<Emits>();
const props = defineProps<Props>();

const checkBoxes =ref({
    canOnline: false
});
const emitCanOnline = (checked: boolean) => {
    emit('canOnline',checked)
}
</script>
<template>
    <n-checkbox
        @update:checked="emitCanOnline"
        v-model:checked="checkBoxes.canOnline" label="online services"/>
</template>
```

If i change `defineEmits<Emits>()` to `defineEmits(['canOnline'])` IDE warnings will be disappear but I want to do it in `TypeScript` way and stick to `TypeScript` , How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type argument given to `defineEmits` declares the allowed function signatures for the resulting `emit()` call.

Since you want to be able to call `emit()` with `"canOnline"` as the first argument, and a boolean as the second argument, the `Emits` interface should be declared as:

```js
export interface Emits {
  (e: 'canOnline', value: boolean): void;
}
```